# How to write a csv file when it's original excel or Libreoffice Cal cell has double lines entries?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, csv, libreoffice-calc

In excel or libreoffice cal, a cell can have multiple line entries.

```
Row Fruit       Like/Dislike
--- ----------  ------------
1   apple       Like
    orange
2   pineapple   Dislike
3   kiwi        Like
    banana 
4   starfruit   Dislike
```

I had first saved the spreadsheet as a "test.csv" file.

Next, I used Python3's csv module to read in the file.
Assuming I had changed pineapple preference to "Like".
Thereafter, I want to write out the amended data to a new csv file.

How do I write data to the new csv without the following issue?

```
Row Fruit       Like/Dislike
--- ----------  ------------
1   apple       Like
2   orange
3   pineapple   Like
4   kiwi        Like
5   banana 
6   starfruit   Dislike
```

Desired outcome:

```
Row Fruit       Like/Dislike
--- ----------  ------------
1   apple       Like
    orange
2   pineapple   Like
3   kiwi        Like
    banana 
4   starfruit   Dislike
```

The command that I had used are:

```
 with open("out.csv", "w", newline='\n', encoding='utf_8' ) as out:
     for v in data.values():
         out.write( f'{v.number},{v.results["Fruit"]},{v.results["Choice"]}\n' )
```

What is the correct command to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Danny_ds, I needed to use python3's csv writer. Also, I needed to set the writer's keyword `dialect='excel'`. That solved my issued. So my command finally looked like this:

```
with open( "out.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8' ) as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer( csvfile, dialect='excel' ) #Use csv writer with excel dialect.
    for v in data.values():
        csvwriter.write( [v.number,v.results["Fruit"],v.results["Choice"]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the multiline fields in quotes like this:

```
"apple
orange",Like
pineapple,Dislike
"kiwi
banana",Like
```

When fields already contain quotes those should be escaped with another quote:

```
"Monitor 24""
Samsung",...
```

Or if you are exporting from the software, look for a parameter to enclose those fields in quotes.

Comment: I have added the command I had used. Can you show me the correct write commands to use?

Comment: @SunBear I don't know Python that well, but I think a csv writer should be used together with a quotechar parameter. But is the problem in the exported `test.csv`or in the `data.values()`? What do both look like?

Comment: Thanks. Using csv writer is correct. But not use `quotechar`. Instead, I had to use `dialect='excel'`.